# Insert / Select in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select all `pat_id` and its `pat_date_hired` in the `patient` table, and then insert it in the `appointment` table.

`pat_id` is the same value as `pat_id` in the `appointment` table, and `pat_date_hired` will be the value of `app_date`, but the year must be changed to the current year.

For example: If `pat_date_hired` = `10-26-2014`, then `app_date` must be `10-26-2016`.

Here is the idea:

```
insert into appointment (pat_id, app_date, app_type) 
values
(*select the pat_id and pat_date_hired and change the year to current year*, "PE")
```

I'm new to MySQL. I have very limited knowledge. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try using DATE_FORMAT to change the year

example as below

```
insert into appoinment (pat_id, app_date, app_type) value(
SELECT pat_id FROM patient_table where pat_id = appointment_table.pat_id
,
DATE_FORMAT(SELECT pat_date_hired FROM patient_table where pat_id = appointment_table_pat_id, YEAR(current_DATE)+'/%m/%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic I would use in SQL Server (you would need to find the replace for the logic of generating app_date. Similar thing should be available in MySql):

```
INSERT INTO appointment (pat_id, app_date, app_type)
SELECT 
      pat_id
      ,DATEADD(yy, YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(pat_date_hired), pat_date)
      , <value for app_type or app_type column> 
FROM patient_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In first place, I would give you advice on the date format you are using; month-day-year won´t be recognized by mysql; you would be better using Y-m-d

Said that; 1st step, use STR_TO_DATE(date_string, format) to convert your date to a valid mysql date; 2nd step, use YEAR(NOW()) to get current year; 3rd step: concat them. Your query would look like the following:

```
insert into appointment (pat_id, app_date, app_type) 
select pat_id, 
CONCAT(
   YEAR(NOW()), 
   "-", 
   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("10-26-2016","%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%d")
), 
"PE")
```

Note that, I made the query so it would return "Y-m-d" date format, if you wanted it to be "m-d-Y" change this

```
CONCAT(
   YEAR(NOW()), 
   "-", 
   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("10-26-2016","%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%d")
)
```

to this

```
CONCAT(  
   DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("10-26-2016","%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%d"),
   "-", 
   YEAR(NOW()),
)
```